# React jest test try to simulate onClick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, jestjs, react-testing-library, buttonclick

so I have some problems, Please help :)

**Here is my component for testing -**

```
export const Error = ({ message }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  function handleClose() {
    setOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <Snackbar
      data-testid="error-component"
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'center',
      }}
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={6000}
    >
      <Alert elevation={6} variant="filled" onClose={handleClose} severity="error" action={
        <IconButton
          aria-label="close"
          color="inherit"
          size="small"
          onClick={handleClose}
          data-testid="error-close-button"
        >
          <CloseIcon fontSize="inherit" />
        </IconButton>
      }>
        {message}
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
};
```

**and here is my test -**

```
it('render without crash', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Error></Error>, div);
});

it('render error component correctly', () => {
  const { queryByTestId } = render(<Error />);

  expect(queryByTestId('error-component')).toBeTruthy();
});

it('error close button click fired', () => {
  const onClickMock = jest.fn();
  const { queryByTestId } = render(<Error />);

  fireEvent.click(queryByTestId('error-close-button'));
  expect(onClickMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(onClickMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

and i got this error -

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

Comment: You can test the state of `open` after simulating the click.

Comment: hmm i do many sarches but dont understand how to do that

Comment: You can't use the mock click approach here. Once you simulate the click, access `Snackbar` and check the value of open.

Comment: but by default open set true

Comment: That is fine, Once `handleClose` trigger `open` value will change to false. That you can expect

Comment: Doesn't seem `onClickMock` is used anywhere so won't be called. Checking if a mock is called ties it a little too closely to the implementation rather than testing the user behaviour of the components, so perhaps fire the event on the close button then check for an element that you expect to disappear. See https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance#waiting-for-disappearance . Can only deduce that this is the OP's intention from the code given.

Answer (score 0):

As ourmaninamsterdam said, I think it's better to make sure that `error-close-button` disappears from the screen rather than calling onClick.

I think this confirmation is a guarantee that onClick was called.

```
it("error close button click fired", async () => {
    render(<Error message="error" />);

    expect(screen.queryByTestId('error-close-button')).toBeTruthy();

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('error-close-button'));

    await waitFor(() => 
        expect(screen.queryByTestId('error-close-button')).toBeFalsy();
    )
});
```